# Why the erf functions have no range error?

Tags: c, math, range, errno, math.h

The `erfcf(FLT_MAX)` produces `0.0f` and sets `errno` to `ERANGE`.

The `erff(FLT_MAX)` produces `1.0f` and does not set `errno` to `ERANGE`.

In both cases returned results differ from the "true results" (i.e. obtained with infinite precision).

Why `ERANGE` is set only for `erfcf`?

Comment: `erfc(large_and_positive)` underflows; `erf(large_and_positive)` does not.

Comment: Thanks. My initial guess was the same. Per C11 "range error occurs if the mathematical result of the function cannot be represented in an object of the specified type, **due to extreme magnitude**". So, in case of `erff(FLT_MAX)` the result of the function cannot be represented in an object of the specified type _not_ due to extreme magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

1. As a general rule, math functions setting `errno` is considered an obsolescent feature, because IEEE infinities, NaNs, and floating point exception flags are considered a superior method of reporting errors for mathematical calculations.  This does not seem to be stated explicitly anywhere in the Standard, but see generally [7.12.1 Treatment of error conditions [in math functions]](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.1), particularly the discussion of `math_errhandling`.
2. `erfc(x)` goes to zero, and `erf(x)` to one, quite rapidly as x increases; `erfc(10)` is already on the order of `2e-45`.  The most precise way to describe the result of `erfcf(FLT_MAX)` and of `erff(FLT_MAX)`, in the terminology of IEEE 754, is as an *inexact* zero or one, respectively.  However, even in an implementation conforming to Annex F, library functions are not required to report inexactness ([F.10p8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.10p8)).
3. A mathematical result that is so close to zero that it cannot be represented exactly is an *underflow* condition (7.12.1p6).  Underflow conditions may, but are not required to, set errno to ERANGE.
4. A mathematical result that is so close to *one* that it cannot be represented exactly is not considered to be any of the error conditions described in 7.12.1, and therefore is *not* to be reported by setting errno.